# Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS desktop installation hangs

Tags: 14.04

I have a system with dual boot, Windows 2008 server and Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS server 32bits.
I want to install Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS desktop 64bits. And don't need Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS server 32bits. I have a DVD and when I boot from the DVD, Installation shows Ubuntu for few minutes and then system is unresponsive. 
I want this specific version of Ubuntu.

I have tried this on 2 separate systems. Also tried burning another DVD in case the first one is corrupted.

Can you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: What are the hardware specs of the server?

Comment: I only ask because I'm confused why you would install a 64bit OS on a system that is 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [32 bit](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/trusty/) (i386) install of the 14.04.1 download. The 64 bit version won't work on your 32 bit system.

If you *need* the 64 bit version, I can't help you with that - someone else might chime in with a virtual solution, but I have no experience in that area.

Answer (score 0):

If your system is only 32 bit (32 bit processor) then you can't install 64 bit OS on that. You need 64 bit hardware to install 64 bit OS or applications. You can try use qemu virtualisation solution to run 64 bit OS on 32 bit processor. You can check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15786/how-can-i-install-a-64bit-linux-virtual-machine-on-a-32bit-linux/15788#15788) post.

Other virtualisation solution like Virtualbox or VMWare doesn't support running 64 bit OS or application on 32 bit processor. HTH